# configure rails for observing User registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, observer-pattern

Here is my action do_registration in UserController

```
  def do_registration

    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
        format.html { render action: "do_registration" }
      else
        format.html { render action: "registration" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

I want to use a UserObserver instead to call the ActionMailer in the action so i writed in observers/user_observer.rb theese line of codes:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe User

  def after_save(user)
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  end
end
```

i added

```
config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
```

in my environment.rb, but when i register new user no mail is sent.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to write this line `observe User` in observer as you created this with model name only it will by default observe User class. But if you want to mention it explicitly it should be like this `observe :user`.

Comment: but what i need to write in do_registration of my controller when i delete UserMailer.welcome.... line?

Comment: everything else is correct just remove that line and it should work. `after_save` will do the trick in sending the mail.

Comment: it doesn't work. It add new user in database but no mail is sent

Comment: omg, i restarted the server and now it works ... thank you (the line config.active_record.observers = :user_observer must be inserted in application.rb)